# Remove taskbar and time displayed in right corner and move to upper middle of the screen

Tags: gnome, ubuntu-gnome, gnome-shell

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 17.10, gnome-tweak-tool .

I want to remove the bar which is showing at the bottom of the screen and in the upper bar I don't want that "places" option to be shown. I also want time to be shown in the middle of the upper bar.

[image: desktop screenshot]